# How download url with extension while renaming on curl?

Tags: bash, curl

I am new at coding and i need help. I use curl `-o "$filename.$e"` for downloading many file. All work good, but litle bit slow because $e variable determined by if command system

```
 if [[  url =~ ^.*gif.*$ ]]; then
 e=gif
 elif [[ url =~ ^.*jpg.*$ ]];then
 e=jpg
elif [[ url =~ ^.*png.*$ ]]; then
  e=png
 else echo Corrupted link!!!
 fi
```

which take time to response. How i can get extension while downloading like
`curl -o "$filename.*$"`

Comment: What do you mean "by if command system"?  If the $e variable must be set before the command is executed; so, there should be no performance issues.  I don't follow what you are trying to accomplish by "curl -o "$filename.*$".  If filename=asdf, then $filename.*$ is "asdf.*$"; i.e., there is no variable expansion.